# My library gym cannot import to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

why me import the gym in jupyter notebook, No module named 'gym' ??? I have the environment and succesfully to install gym, but when Im trying to import is no module
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaDzU.png)

im trying to re-installing anaconda with downgrade versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to `import gymnasium as gym`?

I would update to v.0.27.0 because you’re in the last version installed that is still `gym`.

https://www.gymlibrary.dev/

Also, if you can’t update, look at this:

https://medium.com/@lynzt/no-module-named-gym-jupyter-notebook-4c75fb55e299

It wouldn’t be the first time that the installation path has to be rebuilt inside the notebook.

Comment: thank you bro, your solution has succesfully

Comment: Perfect!!! So, please acknowledge the answer as correct, please. Like that others can know when searching.